copy Linux EXT filesystem use dd
I used binwalk to scan firmware image, uncompressed & raw RAM dump. When scan for signatures with -I flag there is reference to Linux EXT filesystem:
DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
... ... 
2148245       0x20C795        Linux EXT filesystem, blocks count: 1048741, image size: 1073910784, invalid state invalid error behavior invalid major revision rev 611745794.9334, ext2 filesystem data (mounted or unclean), UUID=a200288c-6200-14af-a200-2c8c62006200, volume name "¢"

I want extract that filesystem use dd command:
dd if=image.out of=ext2-filesystem bs=1 skip=2148245 count=1048741

On output I got file 1,0 MiB (1 048 741 bytes).
I'm not sure that this is correct result, the file is too small. What should be the correct command for this?
EDIT:
GNU Coreutils,
$ dd --version
dd (coreutils) 8.32


(1) What is the question? (2) I did dd if=/dev/urandom count=2M of=random && binwalk -I random and also found EXT with "invalid state invalid error behavior invalid major revision". Meaningless. Your file is not random data by itself, but the alleged EXT may be a false positive. (3) "Blocks count" is not "bytes count". The block size seems to be 1024 bytes here.

You specified blocksize=1 (bs=1) and count=1048741, that gives a file size of 1MB. As Kamil stated, the blocksize is 1024 (1073910784 / 1024 = 1048731). So you may get the image you desire by simply specifying bs=1024. Also recalculate the skip= value to fit the beginning of the assumed image in the dump.

2148245 is not divisible by 1024, so recalculating skip= while using bs=1024 is not really possible. In dd from GNU coreutils 9.0 or later skip=2148245B should work regardless of bs=, I think. Earlier versions could do this with skip=2148245 iflag=skip_bytes. Portably one needs to keep bs=1 and to recalculate count=.

dd if=image.out of=ext2-filesystem bs=1024 skip=2148245B count=1048741
dd: invalid number: ‘2148245B’

B isn't a valid suffix. Please read the documentation man dd (search for suffix)
