How to extract files from EXT2 filesystem
debian11. I copied EXT2 filesystem from some dump file. I'm not sure if this file is intact or has no errors.
$ file ext2file
ext2file: Linux rev -1358692254.9334 ext2 filesystem data (mounted or unclean), UUID=a200288c-6200-14af-a200-2c8c620018af, volume name "\242" (64bit) (large files)

I tried extfstools, but it can't (possibly I used it incorrectly)
$ ./ext2rd ext2file ./:savedir
Segmentation fault

Is it possible to extract files from it?

Try R-Studio Undelete for Linux (it's free). If it doesn't work, well, tough luck. There are tools to extract files by their headers but if files in your image are fragmented, well, you won't be able to extract them.

@ArtemS.Tashkinov The software isn't free. R-Studio Demo Mode is limited to files smaller than 256 KB. The basic version costs $79.99.

@ChanganAuto https://www.r-studio.com/free-linux-recovery/ I said it's free, and it's free

Your previous question ( https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/779474/copy-linux-ext-filesystem-use-dd ) showed the file was indicated as being corrupt.  This is likely not an ext2 dump and is a false-detection (as was mentioned on your earlier question)

This looks pretty broken. It's extremely unlikely that someone labeled their file system with a single non-ASCII character. And it's impossible that they set the revision to a negative gigantic number.
My guess is that this has been copied from the wrong offset. You could look through the file, manually or using binwalk, for ext2 signatures. I wouldn't get my hopes up. This is probably only being displayed by file as ext2 filesystem because it has a random accumulation of the right bytes at its beginning, not because it's actually an ext2 file system.
